# Converting monetary amount to cents in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I want to be able to safely take monetary values, that look like 5 or 5.12 dollars and convert them to cents, like 500 and 512 respectively.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    price: 5.1
  },
  computed: {
    amount() {
      return (this.price * 100);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <label>Total amount (formatted)<br>
<input v-model="price"></label>
  </label>

  <p>

    <label>Total amount (cents) {{ amount }}<br>
<input v-model.number="amount" name="amount" required type="number"></label>
</div>
```

I've noticed that values like "5.10" can makes it not convert to cents cleanly.

I also want to avoid people entering values like 5.1 and 5.12345, since they are not really monetary. Cents should be double digits right?

Any tips to avoid costly mistakes here please?

Comment: how about `Math.round(this.price * 100)`?

Comment: I wonder if I could do a warning too if someone enters "5.11312", i.e. going beyond two decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could use `Math.round` to round the cent to the nearest integer

Moreover, to detect entering value over 2 decimal place, [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) that value and check

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    price: 5.1
  },
  computed: {
    amount() {
      return Math.round(this.price * 100);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    price(newPrice, oldPrice) {
      if (String(newPrice).split('.')[1]?.length > 2) {
        alert('Should not input number over 2 decimal places')
        this.price = oldPrice
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <label>Total amount (formatted)<br>
<input v-model="price"></label>
  </label>

  <p>

    <label>Total amount (cents) {{ amount }}<br>
<input v-model.number="amount" name="amount" required type="number"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Instead of an alert, could the message be in the same form/style as the required dialog that html does?

Comment: @hendry sure it could, `alert` here is just for demo, you could do any other things you want

Comment: Little puzzled in VueJS (maybe another question) on how to control when the form can submit or not. For example if "foo" is entered, what is the UX? Pretty poor right now.

Comment: @hendry in my opinion, you should display message somekind of "Invalid number"

Answer (score 0):

you can  [use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) `Number.toFixed` specifying `2` the number of digits after the decimal point. this will return a `string` then you can convert it back again to number using `Number.parseFloat`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    price: 5.1
  },
  computed: {
    amount() {
      return Number.parseFloat((this.price * 100).toFixed(2));
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <label>Total amount (formatted)<br>
<input v-model="price"></label>
  </label>

  <p>

    <label>Total amount (cents) {{ amount }}<br>
<input v-model.number="amount" name="amount" required type="number"></label>
</div>
```